# Constructor that Dynamically allocates an array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, constructor

I'm having trouble grasping constructors and specifically how you can dynamically allocate an array within one.  Could someone possibly give an example of a class that has an array of floating-point numbers and the constructors accepts an integer arg and dynamically allocates an array to hold that many numbers.

And how other member functions would go about access that array.

Thanks for the assistance and any other helpful insights are much appreciated.

EDIT: I have not learned std:vector yet, is there an even simpler way?

Comment: Writing your own resource management code is never simpler than using the standard library.

Comment: The vactor _is_ the simpler way.  Doing without a vector is _harder_.  That's why people keep mentioning it.

Comment: I fully agree with Mooing Duck: **The standard library is part of C++.** It's there for a reason. Learn it. Use it. It makes life *so* much easier. Only go into the gory implementation details once you have developed a solid grasp on the language.

Answer (score 3):

This is more or less what `std::vector` does, though that one is implemented with significantly greater generality in mind, so it's a bit hard for a newcomer to read the source of any library implementation (especially given the usually nightmarish naming conventions used in standard library code).

Here's baby's first dynamic array:

```
class MyArray
{
  float * buf;
  std::size_t size;

public:
  explicit MyArray(std::size_t s) : buf(new float[s]), size(s) { }
  ~MyArray() { delete[] buf; }

  // Copying and reassigning is tricky! We disallow it for now.
  MyArray(MyArray const &) = delete;
  MyArray & operator=(MyArray const &) = delete;

  std::size_t size() const { return size; }
  float & operator[](std::size_t i) { return buf[i]; }
  float const & operator[](std::size_t i)  const { return buf[i]; }
};
```

This is exception-safe: the only time an exception could happen is in the initializer list of the constructor, and there is only one such occasion (`new`). Should an exception happen, nothing will be leaked, since nothing else has been allocated at that point.

Usage:

```
MyArray a(20);
a[4] = 6.3;
```

A more advanced version would include a `resize()` feature; for that, you'll have to allocate and copy (say):

```
void resize(std::size_t n)
{
  float * tmp = new float[n];
  std::copy(buf, buf + std::min(size, n), tmp); // I assume this doesn't throw

  delete[] buf;

  buf = tmp;
  size = n;
}
```

Once you understand what the assignment operator is supposed to do, you can use an idea very similar to that of `resize()` to assign one `MyArray` to another.

Comment: I have not learned std:vector yet, is there an even simpler way?

Comment: @Extinct23: I think in ten years' time when you're a C++ guru you'll look back and this and laugh at how simple and beautiful `vector` is :-) (It's really not *complicated*, just *general*.)

Comment: I don't think it's responsible to show this code without the necessary copy constructor and copy assignment operator... (Also, `return size();` is infinite recursion.)

Comment: @Extinct23: Sorry, I got the operator wrong, I meant it to be the square-bracket operator. Fixed.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I recognize its probably a beautiful feature, but currently I know next to nothing about vector, and therefore I honestly, do not know what is going on in the your response.  I'm just looking for an example in its simplest form.  I think it would help bring the concept full circle

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks - responsibility increased!

Comment: @Extinct23: Well... how much C++ do you know? This is really the simplest example of a resource-managing class... it has non-trivial constructor, destructor (and copy and assignment, which I skip), as it has to... it's really a very compact demonstration of the core idea of C++. If you're entirely baffled by everything that's going on, it'd perhaps be best to grab a coffee and a good book and check back here a little later. It's all fun, I'm sure you'll enjoy learning all this!

Comment: @KerrekSB Not really. Using C++11 syntax to just circumvent the problem is nothing near just giving correct copy semantics. C'mon, they're not that complex to write.

Comment: @ChristianRau: They're not in the scope of the question.  No need to confuse/intimidate the OP further.

Comment: @Mooing : On the other hand, leading the OP directly into UB and memory corruption doesn't exactly help them either. Maybe they _ought_ to be intimidated by classes that own raw resources -- then they'll take the "easy" way, i.e. use the standard library.

Comment: Hands up anyone who wants me to spell out the copy constructor and assignment operator, and who doesn't think that is inappropriate for SO (given that this is a Q&A and not a tutorial website). I'm happy to write it, I just don't want to upset those who think this is beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: I feel like there's a homework question floating in the background of this, I vote leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Array_holder
{
    float* arr;

    Array_holder(size_t size):
    arr(new float[size])
    {}

    ~Array_holder()
    { delete[] arr; }

    float get(size_t i) const
    { return arr[i]; }
};
```

writing this rather simple code I made 2 rude mistakes:

1) I forgot to free memory
2) I haven't implemented copy constructor and assignment operator that according to rule of 3 are required if class have destructor.

This is good example why working with dynamic memory is complicated and dangerous. Compare with following example:

```
#include <vector>

struct Array_holder
{
    std::vector<float> arr;

    Array_holder(size_t size):
    arr(size)
    {}

    float get(size_t i) const
    { return arr.at(i); }
};
```

This example is shorter, simpler, more readable, less error-prone and more reliable in usage.

Comment: Without a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, this class will corrupt memory very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

First, because you're using C++, you should just be using a `std::vector`.

Second:

```
class DynamicArray {
    float* array;
public:
    DynamicArray( int size ) { array = new float[ size ]; }
    ~DynamicArray( void ) { delete[] array; }
    float* get( void ) const { return array; }
};
```

Comment: I have not learned std:vector yet, is there an even simpler way?

Comment: I think `std::vector` is the simplest way because all of the code is written for you and has already been thoroughly tested.

Comment: Without a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, this class will corrupt memory very quickly.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, I see that now. Good call. And this is why everybody should just use the standard library -- to avoid such errors. I wonder if I can delete my own answer, as damage control ...